# Hive: regexp_replace square brackets

Tags: hive, square-bracket

I need to replace the square brackets around a key:value pair similar to the following.  Any help is much appreciated!

data in 'properties' looks like this:

```
name: property1
value: [12345667:97764458]

**code**
SELECT p.name, regexp_replace(p.value,'[','') AS value
FROM properties p
```

Solved: Revised code

```
SELECT p.name, regexp_replace(p.value,'\\[|\\]','') AS value
FROM properties p;
```

Comment: code: regexp_replace(p.value,'\\[|\\]','')  works

Answer (score 4):

You always need to double your backslashes in Hive regexes. That's because a single backslash is used as an escape character in Hive strings so it would get stripped off before the regex parser can see it. A double backslash becomes a single backslash, which is what you need.

To see how backslashes get stripped just run a select using your regex as a string literal:

```
select '\\[' from t limit 1;
OK
\[
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is you regex `[\[\]]+` this will match one or more `[` and `]` in a string.

Comment: João, thanks. I'm still getting an error running this. Maybe I'm using the code incorrectly? Please see the revised code in the original submission.

Comment: pe.value does not exist, you table name alias is 'p'.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the code above. I added the error returned.